# Storing values of multidimensional array into variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```
$res = $db->getArticles($db);
$hey = print_r($res, TRUE);
echo $hey['0'];
```

Here is the code for `$db->getArticles`:

```
public function getArticles() {
    $array = array();
    try {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id");
        $sth->execute();
        foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
            $array[] = $row;
        }
        return $array;
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

The logic is that the function queries the database and puts everything into an array. The number of rows in the table will always be pretty low, so performance isn't an issue.

The following is the output of the first code snippet above:

```
echo $hey['0']; // prints "A" (without the quotes).
echo $hey['1']; // prints "r"
echo $hey['2']; // prints "r"
echo $hey['3']; // prints "a"
echo $hey['4']; // prints "y"
```

As you can see, it spells out the word "Array."

`echo $hey` prints the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [author] => 0 [content] => This Is a Test [publication_date] => 1380380992 ) )
```

My end goal is to store each individual value into a variable and do something with it. This would all happen inside a for loop which runs on the array so I can get information from each row.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) just prints a string detailing the array, the `true` option just returns the string instead of printing it out directly. It doesn't put the actual data array into the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array( array( ID => 1, 
                  author => 0,
                  content => "This Is a Test",
          publication_date => 1380380992
                )
         );



echo $array['0']['author'];
```

This works for me...

just echo `echo $array['0']['author'];` and replace author by the field you need.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! I tried it but its still the same, except I have a notice too now:

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'content' in...A`. The error is on that line.

Comment: Can you maybe try again?

Comment: `echo $hey['0']['0'];` prints just "A" without the warning, but I get "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1" if I do `echo $hey['0']['1'];` or `echo $hey['0']['2'];`

Comment: the problem is `print_r` does not return array data, using `$hey['0']` or any other array syntax with `$hey` you are just accessing the individual characters that make up the returned string.

Comment: You need to use the array, not $hey ;) Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$hey = print_r($res, TRUE);
```

This will return a string that gives the info of the array `$res`. If you echo it, you should expect to see the same as what `print_r($res);` displays, as you've shown. `$res` is already an array of your query data, so loop over that.

```
foreach($res as $row) {  //row loop
  foreach($row as $col) {  //column loop
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried replacing `// do something` with `echo $res[$row][$col];` and got "Warning: Illegal offset type" on that echo line 4 times.

Comment: The variable would be just `$col`. If you did a nested *for* loop, the syntax would be like you tried.